# Formal definition of a knot diagram, including data for the crossings

Tags: knot-theory

The definition of a knot diagram has, in some sense, two parts: the 2-dimensional projection itself, packaged with the corresponding data about where the over- and under-crossings are. It's easy enough to see what is meant by the first part, in the strictest formal sense: it's just a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. However, most definitions tend to hand-wave away how exactly the crossing data is "packaged". Of course, in some sense it doesn't matter, but as a student learning these things for the first time, I'd feel more comfortable having an explicit, formal definition. Does anyone know of a reference for one?

Comment: Define a crossing to be a point that locally looks like an x. For each one, specify a specific pair of opposite branches of the x to be the "overcrossing".
(The projection, by the way, should probably be smooth, with no self-tangencies or triple intersections.)

Comment: Here are some notes on the combinatorial data of a knot diagram, suitable for computations: https://math.berkeley.edu/~kmill/2019_8_25/gauss_dt_codes.html